# MySQL Remote connectivity Security

Tags: mysql, sql, security, remote-access

Recently I was trying to convince my hosting provider to secure my remote connection to `MySQL`. Their reply was that these connections are by default `unsecured` and even big players provide only unsecured remote connections to MySQL. I did a lot of Googling but I was unable to get a satisfactory answer.

If I wish to have my remote connection to `MySQL` server secure, am I wishing wrong?

Because I believe no remote connection be insecure. Even the latest versions of MySQL Workbench have stopped supporting `nonsecure` connections.

Answer (score 0):

To make your whole website secure beside your database , you need to issue SSL certificate and make it work under https which is going to encrypt all the data of your website.
in addition , its always good to avoid mysql default port , change it to  some other port number than 3306 which makes it harder for attacker to attack your mysql connection.